# Apache virtual hosts in jail enviroment

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, jail

I have a linux server with a chroot user jail environment. Users files are kept under

```
/jail/username/httpdocs
```

and are currently resolvable under

```
http://IPADDRESS/~username
```

I need users to be able to setup their own virtualhost config rather than using global apache2.conf i.e user will create file

```
/jail/username/vdomains/domain.com.conf
```

and it will put their virtual host information. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, but not a great idea. The only real way to do this is include those files in the main apache config; but in doing so they can put directives that are not vhost specific in those files. Letting them configure the vhost allows them to loadmodules into the apache process or apply serveraliases that may be owned by other tenants.

As far as I know, the only way to safely allow untrusted users to modify their own configurations is to run a separate httpd service for each and reverse-proxy connections to each from a main, but this runs into difficulty in knowing the correct hostnames for each, as well as SSL parameters.